# Adding a transformed parameter to stanfit object

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I have a `stanfit` object called `fit` returned by `rstan::stan(...)` to infer a parameter `theta`. I can now analyse `theta` using e.g. `rstan::summary(fit, pars="theta")`.

I later realised that I am more interested in inference about the square of `theta`. I should have included a `transformed parameters` block in the STAN model to include `theta_squared` as a parameter in the output.

Is it possible to add the transformed parameter `theta_squared <- theta^2` to the existing `stanfit` object, as if it had been calculated in a `transformed parameters` block?

Comment: We hope to add a way to do this automatically by running the generated quantities block after the parameters have been drawn;  but it'll be a while before this is coded and released.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can (or should) add a parameter to the stanfit object manually.
At least you can get the MCMC samples by `as.data.frame(fit)`, and then play with it as you wish, including defining `theta^2`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I would like to be able to use all the rstan functions like `stan_rhat`, `stan_ac` etc on the transformed parameter. It seems like the easiest way to achieve that is to add it to the `stanfit` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a lot of those same graphs (rhat, ac, etc) using ShinyStan, which does allow you to add a quantity like this (if it's a scalar). For example,

```
library("shinystan")
# create shinystan object (sso)
sso <- as.shinystan(fit)
# add theta_squared to sso
sso <- generate_quantity(sso, fun = function(x) x^2, 
                         param1 = "theta", new_name = "theta_squared")
# launch the shinystan interface
launch_shinystan(sso)
```